# How can I add another TextView in my Listview?

Tags: android, listview, textview, adapter

I've made a ListView by following a tutorial on the web. It works great and exactly like I want it to. Now I'm trying to create another ListView in another activity but this time I need two TextViews, not one.

Here's my Adapter:

```
public class CustomListTwo extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
// private final String[] hex; <-- was trying to add this one but it gave me an error :(
private final Integer[] imageId;

public CustomListTwo(Activity context,
                     String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_item_layout, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_value);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_color);

    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return rowView;

    }
}
```

I'm trying to add "String[] hex;" but it gives me an error saying that the "variable may not be initialized". My idea was to duplicate everything that was written about the web variable and replace it with the hex variable and change the values.

Here's my activity:

```
public class ColorRed extends Activity {

ListView list;
String[] web;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.color.red_50,
        R.color.red_100,
        R.color.red_200,
        R.color.red_300,
        R.color.red_400,
        R.color.red_500,
        R.color.red_600,
        R.color.red_700,
        R.color.red_800,
        R.color.red_900,
        R.color.red_A100,
        R.color.red_A200,
        R.color.red_A400,
        R.color.red_A700,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_red);

    web = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);

    CustomListTwo adapter = new
            CustomListTwo(ColorRed.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_red);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: r50(view);
                    break;
                case 1: r50(view);
                    break;
                default:
                    r50(view);
                    break;
            }

          }
       });
    }
```

Here's my ListView item:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="72dp"
   android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

   <ImageView
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_color"
    android:src="@drawable/myrect" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_hex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:textColor="#de000000"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="List Item"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textColor="#de000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/item_value"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

So basicly, my question is how do I add a new TextView and load it with an array from strings.xml just like I do with the current TextView? I want the TextView "hex" to be populated with text from an array which I declare in strings.xml.

EDIT: My updated adapter:

```
    public class CustomListTwo extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final String[] hex;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomListTwo(Activity context, String[] web, String[] hex, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web, hex);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.hex = hex;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_item_layout, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_value);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_color);

        TextView txtHex = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_hex);
        txtHex.setText(hex[position]);

        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Updated activity:

```
public class ColorRed extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String[] web;
    String[] hex;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.color.red_50,
            R.color.red_100,
            R.color.red_200,
            R.color.red_300,
            R.color.red_400,
            R.color.red_500,
            R.color.red_600,
            R.color.red_700,
            R.color.red_800,
            R.color.red_900,
            R.color.red_A100,
            R.color.red_A200,
            R.color.red_A400,
            R.color.red_A700,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_red);

        web = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);
        hex = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hex_red);

        CustomListTwo adapter = new
                CustomListTwo(ColorRed.this, web, hex, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_red);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0: r50(view);
                        break;
                    case 1: r50(view);
                        break;
                    default:
                        r50(view);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Now I get an error in this code:

```
super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web, hex);
```

"Cannot resolve method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare a final variable and not initialize it anywhere.

Pass the hex array in your adapter constructor, assign it to the hex[] in the adapter and use it in getView(..).

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I add the variable "hex" to super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web, hex); it gives me an error saying "Cannot reference 'CustomListTwo.hex' before supertype constructor has been called".

Comment: Change the line `super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web, hex);` in the `CustomListTwo` constructor to `super(context, R.layout.color_item_layout, web);`.

Comment: Look at the updated code. It's not the same problem anymore :(